# Get the most consecutive day from Date column with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Original dataframe:**

| member_id | AccessDate |
| --- | --- |
| 111111 | 2020-02-03 |
| 111111 | 2022-03-05 |
| 222222 | 2015-03-04 |
| 333333 | 2021-11-23 |
| 333333 | 2021-11-24 |
| 333333 | 2021-11-25 |
| 333333 | 2022-10-11 |
| 333333 | 2022-10-12 |
| 333333 | 2022-10-13 |
| 333333 | 2022-07-07 |
| 444444 | 2019-01-21 |
| 444444 | 2019-04-21 |
| 444444 | 2019-04-22 |
| 444444 | 2019-04-23 |
| 444444 | 2019-04-24 |
| 444444 | 2019-05-05 |
| 444444 | 2019-05-06 |
| 444444 | 2019-05-07 |

**Result dataframe:**

| member_id | Most_Consecutive_AccessDate | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 2022-03-05 | 1 |
| 222222 | 2015-03-04 | 1 |
| 333333 | 2022-10-11, 2022-10-12, 2022-10-13 | 3 |
| 444444 | 2019-04-21, 2019-04-22, 2019-04-23, 2019-04-24 | 4 |

Describe my question:

- **Each member** has a unique id and **Accessdate** as the first table.
- If the **Member don't have consecutive day**, must get the **latest date**.
- If the **Member have consecutive day more than 1 period**, must get the **most consecutive streak**.
- If the **Member have the same number of consecutive day**, must get the **latest consecutive streak**.

  - **Example** from original table
    **member 333333** have consecutive period as 2021-11-23, 2021-11-24, 2021-11-25 and **2022-10-11, 2022-10-12, 2022-10-13.**
    We need only the last period.

I have tried to use it.

df = df.withColumn('Most_Consecutive_AccessDate', collect_list('AccessDate')

try to get the number in the list But it is too far from the expected result

ps. edit for easier reading and wrong typing

Comment: Added my answer, I'll update with the details on how it works later - let me know if you need any help. It's standard "gap-and-islands" problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work: (Using "gap-and-islands" - will add details shortly)

```
df.select(F.col("member_id"), F.col("AccessDate").cast("Date"))\
.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(Window().orderBy(F.lit('A'))))\
.withColumn("bucket", F.col("AccessDate")-F.col("row_num"))\
.groupBy("bucket", "member_id")\
.agg(F.max("AccessDate").alias("AccessDate"), F.count("*").alias("cnt"))\
.orderBy(F.col("cnt").desc(), F.col("AccessDate").desc())\
.groupBy("member_id")\
.agg(F.first("cnt"), F.first("AccessDate"))\
.show();
```

To know more and learn about series problems - https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-find-the-longest-consecutive-series-of-events-in-sql/

Comment: it has some issue, if the first and second row has the same member_id and access_date like
 
111111  |   2020-02-03 |  2020-02-02
111111  |   2022-02-03 |  2022-02-01
111111  |   2022-02-03 |  2022-01-31

the result might be 111111| 2 | 2022-02-03 
should I shuffle all rows first to avoid this problem or provide a unique col?

Comment: @NewbieGramming Sorry didn't get you - did you mean this?

Row 1 -  111111 | 2020-02-03 
Row 2 -  111111 | 2020-02-03

Comment: hooray!!! I have worked around that by deleting duplicate rows before assigning the row number, and the problem has been solved. very thankful